# Is there a limit to all the ridetypes returned?

Tags: lyft-api

When I submit a GET request for ridetypes, for example, is there a limit to how many rides are in the response? Let's saw I have 20 cars near that specific location. Will all those rides show up or is there a limit?

Comment: Rate limits appear to be per minute according to the docs: https://developer.lyft.com/docs/rate-limits

Comment: I am not asking about how many requests I can make, I am asking about the information returned in a valid request. If I am in a location with a lot of Lyft cars around, will it give me info on all of them or only on some?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting https://api.lyft.com/v1/ridetypes endpoint then it's response is Lyft's ride types not rides, for example, Lyft, Lyft Line, Lyft Plus, Lyft Premier, Lyft Lux, Lyft Lux Suv etc.

And I don't think there is any limit for this endpoint.

You can check response here [Availability Ride Types](https://developer.lyft.com/v1/reference#availability-ride-types)

Comment: Is there a trick to getting the endpoints to show? I get a blank page, even when I log into a readme.io account that I just created.